# Accessing timeline objects from a class, giving null object reference?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

**All late comers this question in still active a answer is not yet reached, what you might see below is a irrelevent syntax error a nice member found for me**

error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Player()
    at Maintest_fla::MainTimeline/createPlayer()
```

When i'm attempted to add the instance name wall0x objects that are in the object with the instance name world, I find that I get a null object error.
Also ignore the long list of variables, not relevant.

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
    import flash.utils.Timer;



    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        // player settings



        private var _rotateSpeedMax:Number = 20;
        public var _gravity:Number = .10;
        // projectile gun settings
        public var _bulletSpeed:Number = 4;
        public var _maxDistance:Number = 200;
        public var _reloadSpeed:Number = 250;//milliseconds
        public var _barrelLength:Number = 20;
        public var _bulletSpread:Number = 5;
        // gun stuff
        private var _isLoaded:Boolean = true;
        private var _isFiring:Boolean = false;
        private var _endX:Number;
        private var _endY:Number;
        private var _startX:Number;
        private var _startY:Number;
        private var _reloadTimer:Timer;
        private var _bullets:Array = [];

        // array that holds walls

        public var _solidObjects:Array = [];

        //
        private var _player:MovieClip;
        private var _dx:Number;
        private var _dy:Number;
        private var _pcos:Number;
        private var _psin:Number;
        public var _trueRotation:Number;



        public function Player()
        {

            // constructor code   //Right hereVVVthe instance name is wall0x and it's in the object world on the stage.                            
                _solidObjects = [MovieClip(root).world.wall01,MovieClip(root).world.wall02,MovieClip(root).world.wall03,MovieClip(root).world.wall04];


            /*addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDownHandler);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUpHandler);*/
           }

        }
}
```

Code I'm using in frame 2 create the player and then continuously set it's chords to another objects.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, createPlayer);
function createPlayer(e:Event):void
        {


            // attach player movieclip from library

            // position player in center
            if (character!=null&&_player!=null)
            {

                _player.x = character.x + 5;
                _player.y = character.y + 5;
            }
            else if (_player ==null && world.wall01 != null)
            {
            var _player:Player;


                _player = new Player();

                // add to display list
                stage.addChild(_player);
            }
        }
```

Comment: When Player constructer is called? is it called in frame 2? If your variables are on frame 2 then I think you have to create the Player object in frame 2...

Comment: Yea, I am creating a player object in frame 2. It's giving me a syntax error when I add the objects to a list like this though.

Comment: So, on frame2 of your main timeline, does `world` exist? (and all of it's walls?) or does it only exist on frame 1?

Comment: It only exists on frame 2, the frame in which I'm  creating the player

Comment: Even when I run it like this it throws null object reference errors `else if (_player ==null && world.wall01 != null)
   {
       var _player:Player;

    
    _player = new Player();

    // add to display list
    stage.addChild(_player);
   }`

Comment: Then `world` is probably what is null.  Are you able to post your .fla to the cloud to have a look at?  Also, when replying to comments,  start with @user so they get an alert that you've replied.

Comment: @LDMS http://www.filedropper.com/final_14 <source and everything. You only really need to look at the 3rd frame and the class Player that I attempted to make. If you like you can look at the commented out Player creation that was working prior to me attempting to make it a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First:**  You have a syntax error in these two lines:

```
_player.x = MovieClip.(root).character.x + 5;
_player.y = MovieClip.(root).character.y + 5;
```

There should not be a period after `MovieClip`, so it should look like this:

```
_player.x = MovieClip(root).character.x + 5;
_player.y = MovieClip(root).character.y + 5;
```

**Second:**  You are always creating a new Player every frame.  In your `createPlayer` method, you have the following conditional:

```
if(character != null && _player != null)  //_player is not a defined in this scope, so it will either throw an error, or always return null/undefined
```

You do not have a `_player` var defined in the scope of that frame or the scope of the `createPlayer` method,  you have defined it inside the scope of the `else` statement (which makes only available in the else statement)

Move the `var _player:Player` to the top of your timeline code with the other frame scoped vars.

**Third**: you are trying to access `root` in your `Player` constructor, the problem with this, is that when the contructor runs, your `Player` is not yet on the display tree, so root is null until you've added player to the stage.

example:

```
_player = new Player(); //this will run your contructor, but root will be null
stage.addChild(_player); //after this, your Player class will now have access to root/stage/parent object
```

Change your `Player` class so it listens for being `ADDED_TO_STAGE` before trying access `root`.

```
    public function Player()
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // constructor code

    }

    private function init(e:Event):void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        _solidObjects = [MovieClip(root).world.wall01,MovieClip(root).world.wall02,MovieClip(root).world.wall03,MovieClip(root).world.wall04];
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDownHandler);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUpHandler);
    }
```

Comment: Edited that isn't really an issue since that code was a reference from the main timeline I don't think I even needed to root.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying?   It's a syntax error at any rate and needs to be corrected for your application to run properly (even if it isn't your main issue)

Comment: Wow, thank you. This really helped me understand how classes and objects interact with the timeline. After implementing your suggested fixes there is still a `TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@447ec041 to flash.display.MovieClip.
 at Player/init()
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
 at flash.display::Stage/addChild()
 at Maintest_fla::MainTimeline/createPlayer()
` Not really sure what this means, I'll reply if I can fix it if you read this and I haven't replied it would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: When i tried it earlier with your .fla I didn't get any errors.   I'm away from my workstation for a few days now though and can't test anything.   Looks like somewhere in the `createPlayer`  method you must be trying convert the stage to a MovieClip.

Comment: Damnit, ok I'll try it again.